# jQuery ajax list ahref to send value in ajax and then go to ahref

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am developing notifications just same like Facebook notifications. i have build using ul>li>a now i want when user click any notification then jQuery ajax to get value of a specific li/a which clicked by user and then send to the URL where user click.

i tried many code but didnt work to get li/a data-id.

**Updated:**
My jQuery working fine before append function but when i am setting data in html by append function then my jQuery code doesn't work.

**Please review my code:**

```
<div class="list-containercontent notify-content" id="notifcations-content" >
    <li data-id="1" role="presentation" class="notifcationid un-read">
        <div class="list-box clearfix">
            <a class="nClick" href="http://localhost:8000/admin/order/11">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="pull-right"> OrderNo </div>
                    <div class="pull-left"> <span class="n-name">User 3</span> </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <p>Revision Completed </p><span class="n-date"> 17-06-2015 - 10:30:34</span></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-id="2" role="presentation" class="notifcationid un-read">
        <div class="list-box clearfix">
            <a class="nClick" href="http://localhost:8000/admin/order/12">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="pull-right"> OrderNo </div>
                    <div class="pull-left"> <span class="n-name">User 2</span> </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <p>Revision Completed </p><span class="n-date"> 17-06-2015 - 10:25:22</span></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-id="3" role="presentation" class="notifcationid un-read">
        <div class="list-box clearfix">
            <a class="nClick" href="http://localhost:8000/admin/order/14">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="pull-right"> OrderNo </div>
                    <div class="pull-left"> <span class="n-name">User 1</span> </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <p>Revision Completed </p><span class="n-date"> 17-06-2015 - 10:05:53</span></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**
now this giving me undefined 
    Updated:

```
$(".notification-items li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).prevAll().length+1);
});
```

Comment: What's the interest of jquery here ? Since you already have <a> tags, the click on the link should be enough to redirect the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and this is working fine for me please check.

you just have to add data-id in ahref

```
$(document).on('click', '.notification-items li a', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).parents('.notifcationid').data('id');
    alert(id);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the following should work.

```
$('li.notificationid a').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).parents('li.notificationid').data('id');
    //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO WITH THE ID HERE (e.g. ajax call or whatever)
    return true //Don't need to call this, but it's here for clarity.  Unless you return false, or add a call to e.preventDefault(), the link will still be clicked and the browser will navigate to the 'href' of the 'a'.
});
```

Comment: @chis Disley i am doing alert but alert is not firing and page is going to ahref link

Comment: It's a typo.  I typed 'notificationid' but your markup has 'notifcationid'.  See this codepen for working example with an alert. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPvBLN

Comment: @chis after setting type but this doesn't working in my html

Comment: Have you checked the codepen?  That's working fine for me, using your markup and my javascript.

Comment: Your update definitely won't work.  You'll need to change .closest('notifcationid') to .closest('.notifcationid') if you're looking for elements with that class

Comment: I'd also probably just use .closest() rather than .parent().closest()

Answer (score 1):

You can append that 'id' at ' url' and then post it to next page. In next page you can access this variable like this

```
$id = $_GET['id']
```

your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#notifcations-content li div a").click(function(){
        alert('selected index : '+$(this).parent().parent().attr('data-id'));

        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+'?id='+$(this).parent().parent().attr('data-id'));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$(".notification-items li").delegate('a','click',function() {
    var id = $(this).parents('li.notifcationid').data('id');
    alert(id);
    return false;
});
```